# Merge two associative array and delete the duplicate one

Tags: php, arrays

I have two associative key value pair of array. I want to merge it into one such that they key remains and the value which have "on_time" in the first array should neglect the value of that key in second array.

Here is my two arrays below

```
[att] => Array
        (
            [841] => on_time
            [842] => not_time
            [843] => not_time
        )

    [entatt] => Array
        (
            [841] => unexcused
            [842] => unexcused
            [843] => late
        )
```

Expected output what I am looking for is

```
[entatt] => Array
    (
        [841] => on_time
        [842] => unexcused
        [843] => late
    )
```

Any help ?

Comment: [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?  And have you looked into `array_merge`?

Comment: Yes, with array_merge I am loosing the keys. Which I don't want to

Comment: @MarkBaker: According to the same documentation: "If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended."

Comment: And even if array_merged didn't append values when it was numeric keys it would still don't do what he asked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($att as $key => $value) {
    $result[$key] = $value !== 'on_time' ? $entatt[$key] : 'on_time';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a way to walk both arrays in one go, and apply a function selecting the correct entry in case of collision. I don't think there's a builtin function for that.

```
function merge2($att, $entatt, $collision){
   $res = $att;
   foreach ($entatt as $key => $value) {
     if (isset($res[$key]))
       $res[$key] = $collision($res[$key],$value);
     else
       $res[$key] = $value;
   }
   return $res;
}
```

You should then be able to use it as follow:

```
merge2($att,$entatt,function($v1,$v2){
   return $v1 !== 'on_time' ? $v2 : $v1;
});
```

It should properly handle cases when `$entatt` or `$att` contain keys not in the other array (although it wasn't clear in your question if this was necessary).